# Blazor Dynamic templates

Tags: .net, templates, dynamic, components, blazor-server-side

Blazor is a great framework but advanced examples are hard to find. I'm trying to understand the best way to achieve something in .NET 6 + Blazor I had implemented with asp.net webforms. I'm going to simplify my request so that it can be easier for someone provide a solution:

1. Have a razor component that will act like a page template and defines "zones" where components can be loaded into. Would like to avoid the usage of c# code inside the template, but a code behind file will be ok. I need the template to be as clean as possible.

**DefaultTemplate.razor**

```
    @* This is a razor component used like a page template *@
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row py-10">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <Zone Name="Left"></Zone>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <Zone Name="Main"></Zone>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <Zone Name="Right"></Zone>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

2. The `<zone>` tag is also a razor component that will receive other components according to the zone name. A zone can have many components inside. Not sure if this component should load it's content (components) because in the case of a template does not have a specific zone, components of the missing zone should be loaded into the mandatory "Main" zone.
3. When a page loads the template, I need to get it's defined zones so that I can present a dropdownlist with the zone names so that the user can choose where to add a component.

If anyone has an example of something similar to this or can share some ideas on how to achieve this I appreciate. I'm sure the solution will be very useful for a lot of people.

Thank you!

**UPDATE (More info)**

So here's a screenshot of the result so far. You can see 3 zones defined by 3 zone components in my template and with a component injected inside each zone.

[image]

My Zone Blazor component (**Zone.razor**):

```
<div style="@_zoneadminborder">
    @if (_zonetitle != "")
    {
        @((MarkupString)_zonetitle)
    }
    @DynamicComponent
</div>

@code {
    private string _zoneadminborder = "";
    private string _zonetitle = "";

    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    RenderFragment DynamicComponent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        _zoneadminborder = @"border: 1px dashed blue; padding: 10px";
        _zonetitle = @"<div class=""badge bg-dark mb-10"">" + Name + " Zone</div>";

        DynamicComponent = builder =>
        {
            //builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(Counter));
            builder.OpenComponent(0, Type.GetType("MyWebsite.Web.Components.Counter,MyWebsite.Web"));

            builder.AddAttribute(1, "CurrentCount", 10);                 
            builder.CloseComponent();
        };
    }
}
```

For now, I'm injecting components in each zone from the zone itself but this is not mandatory since there's a side effect. If a zone is not available in a template, how to reassign components that target that zone into the default `Main` zone?

In the `OnParametersSet()` method, I can query a DB and get all the modules that belong to that zone and inject them one by one.

For this to work, I need to know which zones exist in the loaded template and show a dropdownlist with those zone names so that the user can select a Module from a list, select a Zone and click a button to Add that info into the DB. All zones are forced to refresh so they inject the new modules.

Something like this (not working):

[image]

Maybe having a variable that would provide that info inside DefaultTemplate.razor could work but it would mean to use c# code in the template.

```
@code {
    public string Zones => "Left;Main;Right";
}
```

The Controls to **select a module**, **select a zone** and **Add** it to the zone should stay in a separate component, so the difficulty will be to get the names of the existing zones from the template component, and to be able to force a remote refresh on all the zone components so that they refresh contents.

What do you think of all this? Any changes?

---

**UPDATE (Major turn over)**

Meanwhile found out that any **minimal change** to HTML inside a .razor file **requires it to be compiled**. This inexplicable path of the .net team does not take into account the real world of web development, in my opinion.

So, to deal with this,I decided to use:

- Razor Pages for the page (Runtime Compilation Package installed).
  Here I'm getting all the data from the database and populating my page model.
- View Component for the Zone component or Razor Component? Not quite sure yet. View Components can nicely separate and encapsulate server-side logic necessary to render output and allow the usage of a simple tag helper:

`<vc:zone name="Left" page-data="@Model"></vc:zone>`

Razor Component has a worse looking tag but can provide me other features for communicating with other zones. The tag would look like this:

```
<Component type="typeof(eCM.Web.Components.Shared.Zone)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-name='"Left"' param-pagedata='@Model' />
```

Both of them allow me to pass my Page Model with all the required data using a parameter. For now I'm sticking to the Razor Component for Zones.

- Partial Views for the templates that use Zone  Razor Components to define editable areas. Partial views allows you to receive the Page model so it's easy to pass it to each Zone Razor Component. Here's an example of my template (`_defaultTemplate.cshtml`):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-10">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <Component type="typeof(eCM.Web.Components.Shared.Zone)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-name='"Left"' param-pagedata='@Model' />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <Component type="typeof(eCM.Web.Components.Shared.Zone)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-name='"Main"' param-pagedata='@Model' />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <Component type="typeof(eCM.Web.Components.Shared.Zone)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-name='"Right"' param-pagedata='@Model' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember, you can edit this even with notepad without needing to recompile.

- Blazor for the modules that go into the zones.

This approach, will give you the magical freedom of template editing with NO COMPILATION required. Just open the template in any HTML editor, change things, save it and that's it!

You can check more info and a video of this working at [Github dotnet issues](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41127)

If you also feel the pain I did, let our friends at .NET know, because the future isn't bright with Blazor Server, at least not for those who need to change dynamic webpages quickly and not having to depend on Visual Studio Compiler just to change the class of a DIV. Just insane...

Comment: You can use RenderFragments for HeaderContent and MainContent in your razor component, could you please explain a bit how do you want to load components in these zones?

Comment: Go with Surinder here, you need to be more specific with some example code.  Why does a typical `Zone` look like.  How doe you select the Zone?

Comment: @SurinderSingh and MrCakaShaunCurtis, I've updated the question with more info and some progress.

Comment: More questions!  When you say a `Zone` can have many components, how do you sort out the layout/order of those components?  Is each component a razor component/class or are you hoping to store razor markup as text in your database?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Each reference to a component will have an ID, sort order and zone name, so when adding components to a zone, that info will be taken into account. For now, I would be happy to solve the remaining issues before addressing that one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a VERY basic example of what I think you want in a single demo page. I've hard wired and simplified most of the functionality to keep it short and simple. It shows how to use and build `RenderFragments`.

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering
<div>
    <select @bind="@newZone">
        <option value="1">Left</option>
        <option value="2">Main</option>
        <option value="3">Right</option>
    </select>
    <select @bind="@newComponent">
        <option value="Counter">Counter</option>
        <option value="FetchData">Fetch Data</option>
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.AddComponent>Add</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row py-10">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @GetZone(Zone.Left)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @GetZone(Zone.Main)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @GetZone(Zone.Right)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public List<ComponentItem> Components = new List<ComponentItem>();

    private string newZone = string.Empty;
    private string newComponent = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.Components = new List<ComponentItem>
            {
                new ComponentItem {Page = typeof(Index), Component=typeof(Counter), Zone = Zone.Left, Index = 0},
                new ComponentItem {Page = typeof(Index),Component=typeof(FetchData), Zone = Zone.Main, Index = 0},
                new ComponentItem {Page = typeof(Index),Component=typeof(Counter), Zone = Zone.Right, Index = 0},
                new ComponentItem {Page = typeof(Index),Component=typeof(Counter), Zone = Zone.Right, Index = 1},
            };
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void AddComponent()
    {
        var comp = newComponent switch
        {
            "FetchData" => typeof(FetchData),
            _ => typeof(Counter)
        };
        var zone = newZone switch
        {
            "1" => Zone.Left,
            "3" => Zone.Right,
            _ => Zone.Main
        };
        this.Components.Add(new ComponentItem { Page = this.GetType(), Component = comp, Zone = zone, Index = 0 });
    }

    private RenderFragment GetZone(Zone zone) => (builder) =>
    {
        var list = this.GetComponents(zone);
        foreach (var component in list)
        {
            if (component.Component is not null)
            {
                builder.OpenComponent(0, component.Component);
                builder.CloseComponent();
            }
        }
    };

    private List<ComponentItem> GetComponents(Zone zone)
        => this.Components
        .Where(item => item.Page == this.GetType() && item.Zone == zone)
        .OrderBy(item => item.Index)
        .ToList();

    public class ComponentItem
    {
        public Type? Page { get; set; }
        public Type? Component { get; set; }
        public Zone Zone { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Zone
    {
        Default,
        Left,
        Main,
        Right
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for sample! 
Meanwhile, found out that any little bit of html you change on a .razor file requires the hole thing to be recompiled so using Razor Components as templates is out of the question. With my approach it's sitll possible to use Blazor for Zones/Modules. 

Your code works but I can't have the modules/zones picker on the same page so it's not helping me much. I'm already using RenderFragment to inject the modules in the Zone Component. If you have the time I can post the code I have and maybe you can help from there.

Comment: Found a good example of notifying any Razor component from another by using a Notification Service at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#invoke-component-methods-externally-to-update-state

Comment: @HugoA. Razor Code is compiled into classes by the Razor pre-compiler.  You can't "change" Html code in a razor file on the fly.